# If a Q# function can run classical code that uses bits, will the classical code still run at the speed that quantum computers operate on

Tags: q#

Microsoft [states](https://learn.microsoft.com/quantum/language/type-model#operation-and-function-types):

> A Q# function is a classical subroutine used within a quantum algorithm. It may contain classical code but no quantum operations.

By 'classical code', does that mean 32 bit and 64-bit code and applications? If so, will the classical code run at the extreme speeds that quantum computers operate at?

Comment: Quantum computers are not *faster*. They can compute algorithms that are not expressible under a classical programming model, which are often of a lower complexity class than classical algorithms that for the same problem

Answer (score 2):

In Q# there are both functions and operations. Operations can describe both classical and quantum computations. Functions on the other hand must be deterministic so they can't describe quantum computations. Q# includes both, but only Operations will generate instructions to the target quantum devices/simulators. The rest of the application and data is managed by a C# driver and thus you can run any other classical programs via C#as a part of your Q# application. And as Caleb says quantum computers are not faster, they can only provide computational speedups on select types of problems. For more Q# tips check out my [post](https://www.sckaiser.com/blog/2018/12/22/qsharp-advent.html) from the Q#advent calendar, as well as the Q# docs you already found!

Comment: A minor clarification: Q# functions allow you to perform totally classical computations in the middle of your quantum code. The classical C#/F#/Python/whatever driver code runs before and after your quantum code. In both cases, the computation is purely classical and runs on classical hardware -- which, exactly as Dr. Kaiser says, isn't slower, just different.